# What do we use variance of the error term for in regression analysis?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, variance, linear-model, prediction

So I get that, for simple linear regression where Y = B_0 + B_1(x) + E, Var(Y|x) = Var(E). Variance of the mean response involves it, as does variance of future responses, but is this ever actually used on its own? For what?

For example, if you were given a model where a person's height is the dependent variable and that person's weight is the independent variable, and you were asked to estimate the probability that a person of a given weight would possess height between arbitrary values U and V, which of those three variances would you use to calculate your t-score?

Comment: The error term is used when estimating the interval, $Var(\epsilon) ~\sim N(0,\sigma_\epsilon)$.

Comment: Estimating the interval of what? Of the error term itself? Why would you care about that? And for estimating an interval for your response variable, why wouldn't you use a prediction interval (for a single response) or a confidence interval on sample mean (for mean response)?

Comment: The error term determines the prediction interval length. As for your second question about estimating a probability, this is not compatible with frequentist statistics, you would need a Bayesian approach.